# SSIS Lookup finds no match on varchar field

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

I have a pretty basic lookup transformation that is matching on two varchar fields. The source is varchar(13) and the lookup field is varchar(20). I have a clear match between the two but yet the rows are directed to No match output.

Whenever I have come across this before its usually a leading or trailing space, or a mismatch between data types that causes the problem, but I have checked and double checked and can't see any issue. I even joined the tables with a SQL query and that does return rows.

What other possibilities are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSIS performs comparisons differently from SQL Server. It follows more strict rules, so if you are matching strings, make sure the columns are exactly the same: string lengths, padding, casing, code page, ANSI / Unicode, etc.

Putting Derived Column transformations before the lookup that would normalise these parameters usually helps.